# POST request to Jersey Service

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I am trying to call a post method while passing a json object but when I print the object it is in unitialized form.

I am doing something like 
`curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"distributors":{"distributorId":"5","name":"SA"}}' {path}`

Here's the Java code:

```
package com.rest.resource;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "distributors")
public class Distributor
   {
   @XmlElement
   private long   distributorId;
   @XmlElement
   private String name;

   public Distributor()
      {
      }

   public Distributor(final long distributorId,final String name)
      {
      this.distributorId = distributorId;
      this.name = name;
      }
   @Override
   public String toString()
      {
      return "distributors: {distributorId = " + distributorId + ", name = " + name + "}";
      }
   }
```

Method in the Resource

```
@POST
   @Path("")
   public Response addDistributor(final JAXBElement<Distributor> element)
      {
      final Distributor distributor = element.getValue();
      System.out.println(distributor);
      return Response.status(200).entity(distributor.toString()).build();
      }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Oddly using Jersey 1.3 it works perfectly for me, anything 1.4 or above it doesn't seem to work correctly. Using 1.3 I get `distributors: {distributorId = 5, name = SA}` in my console.

Comment: Hey nothing changed even with Jersey 1.3..

Comment: It works for me if I change `JAXBElement<Distributor> element` back to just `Distributor distributor`. Otherwise I get: `JSONMappingException: No suitable constructor found`

Comment: Can you send me your project?

Answer (score 0):

All I did was change the return type like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/distpost")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response addDistributor(final Distributor distributor) {
    System.out.println(distributor);
    return Response.status(201).entity(distributor.toString()).build();
}
```

And it handles a curl test like this:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"distributor": {"distributorId":5,"name":"SA"}}' <url>
```

Comment: I already tried this after your comment, with Jersey version 1.3 but on loading my Apache was complaining about some Servlet not being there.